# Member Function Pointer with base class argument accepting derived class argument

Tags: c++, events, generics, pointer-to-member

So I'm working on this event management class. I'm storing a list of pointers to member functions of the signature `void (Event*)` where Event is just a struct that stores some random data at the moment.

```
typedef boost::function<void(Event*)> Callback;
typedef vector<Callback> CallbackList;

class EventManager
{
public:
   template<typename T>
   void RegisterEventHandler(const std::string& type, void (T::*handler)(Event*), T* obj)
   {
      mCallbackList[type].push_back(boost::bind(handler, obj, _1));
   }

   void DispatchEvent(const std::string& type, Event* evt)
   {
      for(CallbackList::iterator it = mCallbackList[type].begin(); it != mCallbackList[type].end(); ++it)
      {
         Callback callback = (*it);
         callback(evt);
      }   
   }
private:
   hash_map<std::string, CallbackList> mCallbackList;
};
```

I'm wondering, if it's possible for me to derive different versions of Event, and pass pointers to those member functions into this class? Currently I'm trying this.

```
class MouseEvent : public Event
{
public:
   int testMouseData1;
   int testMouseData2;
   int testMouseData3;
};

class HelloWorld 
{
public:
   void Display(MouseEvent* evt)
   {
      cout << "Hello, world!" << endl;
   }
};


int main(void)
{
   MouseEvent* evt = new MouseEvent();

   HelloWorld* world = new HelloWorld();
   eventManager->RegisterEventHandler("testType", &HelloWorld::Display, world);

   return 0;
}
```

This gives me the following error in XCode.

> error: no matching function for call to '`EventManager::RegisterEventHandler(const char [9], void (HelloWorld::*)(MouseEvent*), HelloWorld*&)`'

Do you know how I can safely pass in a pointer that's expecting a derived class in its function signature? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found a solution that seems to be working for me, but I'm not sure if it's entirely safe to do. I changed the RegisterEventHandler method to cast all of the function pointers that I send in to the same type...

```
 template<typename T1, typename T2>
   void RegisterEventHandler(const String& type, T1 handler, T2* obj)
   {
      void (T2::*evtHandler)(Event*) = (void (T2::*)(Event*)) (handler);
      mCallbackList[type].push_back(boost::bind(evtHandler, obj, _1));
   }
```

now it all seems to just work as I originally intended. But I'm pretty new to all this so I'm not entirely sure if this is a safe thing to do. Any thoughts? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your prototype expects "Event" type then you need to make sure the `void Display(MouseEvent* evt)` function is accepting the "`Event`" type. So change it to `void Display(Event *evt)` Then inside the call you can typecast it back to a `MouseEvent`, assuming that the caller passed an actual `MouseEvent`, referenced as an "`Event`".

Secondly, I believe you may have some other issues with the way you are calling `RegisterEventHandler` since it is in a template but you are not specifying the template type.

Comment: @Harley - Template functions have type inference, so I'd say the way he calls RegisterEventHandler is OK

Comment: function template parameters can be inferred from function arguments, nevertheless explicitly specifying template type would help op determine why instantiation failed

Comment: Agreed, just trying to eliminate all the variables here. Pretty sure the main point @Morgan needs to look at here is the "Event" type vs "MouseEvent".